# Eloquent query check if null when data is on another table

Tags: laravel

I have a table name `EmployeeCourses` that has a relationship with `course_detail` table and I have this eloquent query in Laravel:

```
$result = EmployeeCourses::where([['user_id', '=', '01'],['status','!=', 'Completed'] ])->whereDate('start_date','<=',$current_date)->with('course_details')->get();
```

Can I check if the `course_details` is not equal to null and if null or empty than don't include it in the `$result`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `whereHas('relation')`.

```
$result = EmployeeCourses::where([
    ['user_id', '=', '01'],
    ['status','!=', 'Completed'] 
])->whereDate('start_date','<=',$current_date)
->whereHas('course_details')
->with('course_details')->get();
```

this method will return 'EmployeeCources' only if it has at least one 'Course Detail' is assigned.